# What game development tool can I use on a computer that does not support shaders?

Tags: shaders, sfml, hardware

I tried SFML, but found out that my computer does not support shaders. Given this restriction, what could I use instead?

Comment: Shader support in OpenGL has been around since about 2004. Get a new computer.

Comment: You should still be able to use plain OpenGL with versions ≤ 3.0, which support the [fixed-function pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-function).

Comment: Usually, "what tech to use" questions are off-topic. However, after some thought, I retracted my close vote. I would like to keep this question open because it has a specific and simple set of needs, which people stuck with an old computer actually have to face, and expert knowledge would actually be valuable here.